# Uses of unequal joins

Tags: sql, join

Of all the thousands of queries I've written, I can probably count on one hand the number of times I've used a non-equijoin.  e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.date > tbl2.date
```

And most of those instances were probably better solved using another method.  Are there any good/clever real-world uses for non-equijoins that you've come across?

Comment: FWIW, I've always called those sorts of joins "theta joins", but after googleing around, I see that any join involving a comparison operator, including equals, is technically called a theta join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmasks come to mind. In one of my jobs, we had permissions for a particular user or group on an "object" (usually corresponding to a form or class in the code) stored in the database. Rather than including a row or column for each particular permission (read, write, read others, write others, etc.), we would typically assign a bit value to each one. From there, we could then join using bitwise operators to get objects with a particular permission.

Answer (score 1):

How about for checking for overlaps?

```
select ...
from   employee_assignments ea1
,      employee_assignments ea2
where  ea1.emp_id = ea2.emp_id
and    ea1.end_date >= ea2.start_date
and    ea1.start_date <= ea1.start_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Whole-day inetervals in date_time fields:

date_time_field >= begin_date and date_time_field < end_date_plus_1

Comment: Though this can also be done with CONVERT(date, date_field) = CONVERT(date, target_date)

Comment: Yes it can, but it's not a good idea, because then you have a function-based expression, and the optimizer won't optimize it, and you'll find yourself with a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Just found another interesting use of an unequal join on the MCTS 70-433 (SQL Server 2008 Database Development) Training Kit book. Verbatim below.

*By combining derived tables with unequal joins, you can calculate a variety of cumulative aggregates. The following query returns a running aggregate of orders for each salesperson* (my note - with reference to the ubiquitous AdventureWorks sample db):

```
select
    SH3.SalesPersonID,
    SH3.OrderDate,
    SH3.DailyTotal,
    SUM(SH4.DailyTotal) RunningTotal
from
    (select SH1.SalesPersonID, SH1.OrderDate, SUM(SH1.TotalDue) DailyTotal
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader SH1
    where SH1.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
    group by SH1.SalesPersonID, SH1.OrderDate) SH3
join
    (select SH1.SalesPersonID, SH1.OrderDate, SUM(SH1.TotalDue) DailyTotal
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader SH1
    where SH1.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
    group by SH1.SalesPersonID, SH1.OrderDate) SH4
on SH3.SalesPersonID = SH4.SalesPersonID AND SH3.OrderDate >= SH4.OrderDate
group by SH3.SalesPersonID, SH3.OrderDate, SH3.DailyTotal
order by SH3.SalesPersonID, SH3.OrderDate
```

*The derived tables are used to combine all orders for salespeople who have more than one order on a single day. The join on SalesPersonID ensures that you are accumulating rows for only a single salesperson. The unequal join allows the aggregate to consider only the rows for a salesperson where the order date is earlier than the order date currently being considered within the result set.*

In this particular example, the unequal join is creating a "sliding window" kind of sum on the daily total column in SH4.

Answer (score 0):

Dublicates;

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table a, (
    SELECT
      id,
      min(rowid)
    FROM 
      table
    GROUP BY
      id
  ) b
WHERE
  a.id = b.id
  and a.rowid > b.rowid;
```

Comment: changed in to a join. Still even here is have a positive clause as well as a negative one.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get all of the products to offer to a customer and don't want to offer them products that they already have:

```
SELECT
     C.customer_id,
     P.product_id
FROM
     Customers C
INNER JOIN Products P ON
     P.product_id NOT IN
          (
               SELECT
                    O.product_id
               FROM
                    Orders O
               WHERE
                    O.customer_id = C.customer_id
          )
```

Most often though, when I use a non-equijoin it's because I'm doing some kind of manual fix to data. For example, the business tells me that a person in a user table should be given all access roles that they don't already have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a dirty join of two not really related tables, you can join with a <>.

For example, you could have a Product table and a Customer table.  Hypothetically, if you want to show a list of every product with every customer, you could do somthing like this:

SELECT *
  FROM Product p
    JOIN Customer c on p.SKU <> c.SSN

It can be useful.  Be careful, though, because it can create ginormous result sets.